# Зачем нам нужны синглтоны в С++?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Когда-то давно (лет 7 назад) читал я Александреску. И обратил внимание, что он много места уделял созданию синглтонов. То есть таких типов, чтобы объекты этого типа существовали в программе в единственном экземпляре.

Вопросы:

1. А зачем нам вообще нужны такие объекты, которые существуют в программе в единственном экземпляре?
2. В чем проблема просто тупо создать объект указанного типа один раз в программе и больше не создавать объектов такого типа?
3. Статический член любого класса существует в программе в единственном экземпляре. Это проверяет транслятор и линкер и при попытке создать второй экземпляр статического члена класса выдается ошибка. Чем статический член любого класса не синглтон?

UPD1:

> [@pepsicoca1, поясни третью часть вопроса кодом... не совсем понятно,
>   что именно ты имеешь ввиду.]

Уступая грубому нажиму публикую секретные протоколы синглтоностроения имени меня (пример не транслировал, это импровизация):

```
class shell_singleton;

clacc singleton{
friend shell_singleton;

private:
void method1(){/*some action*/}
void method2(int a){/*some action*/}
void method3(int a,float b){/*some action*/}

public:
};

class shell_singleton{

static singleton singleton_var;

public:

void method1(){singleton_var.method1();}
void method2(int a){singleton_var.method2(a);}
void method3(int a,float b){singleton_var.method3(a,b);}
};

singleton shell_singleton::singleton_var;

void main(){
shell_singleton shell_singleton_var;

shell_singleton_var.method1();
shell_singleton_var.method2(3);
shell_singleton_var.method3(5,10.1);
}
```

В этом примере экземпляр shell_singleton::singleton_var; не может быть создан второй раз.

Попытка создания shell_singleton::singleton_var; приведет к ошибке компиляции или линковки.

Не нужны никакие счетчики создания экземпляров класса.

Все решается средствами компилятора и линкера.

Вместе с тем, даже если создать экземпляр типа singleton, то работать с ним нельзя, так как все его методы приватные.

Но это я перестраховался, проще пользователям не объявлять вообще о существовании класса singleton, пусть работают с классом shell_singleton.

> [@pepsicoca1, поясни третью часть вопроса кодом

А по первым двум частям есть какие-то мысли? А то чего-то все гуру молчат, видать никто не строит синглтоны, зря Александреску так распинался на эту тему. Неактуальная тема видать.

На самом деле я задал этот вопрос еще в одном месте. Вот по этой ссылке можно поглядеть обсуждение:

http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2205986.html

И там, в отличие от стековерфлоу, было несколько ответов. Не скажу, чтобы доводы коллег меня убедили в важности построения синглтонов . Но хоть что-то, хоть какие-то версии.

UPD2:

Подумал тут на досуге. Ну вот создал программист синглтон. Типа защитил себя от ужасных юзеров. А юзер взял и создал DLL и в этой DLL создал второй экземпляр типа синглтона. Никакой компилятор это не отследит, так как DLL транслируется и линкуется отдельно. И от чего вы тогда защитились синглтоном?

Comment: Стоило бы разнести это вопросы отдельно.

Comment: ну наверное хотябы потому, что  сенаторов много, цель у всех одна, но король должен быть единственным...

Comment: Это проблема для писателей [thread-safety](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-safety) библиотек, а не прикладников верхнего уровня

Comment: [Стоило бы разнести это вопросы отдельно.] Можно все разнести на мелкие кусочки. Но вопросы-то связанные между собой.

Comment: [Это проблема для писателей thread-safety библиотек] А какая проблема у писателей thread-safety библиотек завести в библиотеке один экземпляр нужного им класса? И сказать пользователям, что экземпляр уже есть в библиотеке и не надо создавать второй экземпляр в своей программе. Или же, как указано в третьем вопросе, оформить синглтон как статический член класса и тогда транслятор и линкер просто не дадут создать другой экземпляр этого класса.

Comment: [Это проблема для писателей thread-safety библиотек] Да, первый вопрос все равно остается. Зачем писателям thread-safety библиотек иметь экземпляр какого-то класса в единственном экземпляре? И почему такой проблемы нет у прикладников верхнего уровня?

Comment: @pepsicoca1, поясни третью часть вопроса кодом... не совсем понятно, что именно ты имеешь ввиду.

Comment: (Про upd2) тогда уж сразу копируйте все байты объекта-синглтона в новый кусок памяти. Вау, теперь у вас два объекта! Или приведите указатель на объект с приватными полями к `char*`. Вау, теперь можно считать то, что у него в этих полях! Зачем вы сейчас пишете про крайности? Как будто вы строите бункер, который каждый желающий и не желающий хочет сломать. (И да. Как, простите, юзер-длл создаст вам второй экземпляр?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Процитирую уже упомянутый «Design Patterns»:

> #### Назначение
>
> Гарантирует, что у класса есть только один экземпляр, и предоставляет к нему глобальную точку доступа.

От себя:

А теперь по вопросам:

> А зачем нам вообще нужны такие объекты, которые существуют в программе в единственном экземпляре?

Синглтон, как и все паттерны — это только инструмент, который упрощает жизнь, если его использовать по назначению. Так что ответ зачем — потому что так проще сделать и это решение лучше альтернатив (глобальные переменные и функции) в данной конкретной ситуации. Почему так происходит — потому что при реализации просто всплывают какие-то менеджеры, какие-то фабрики, какие-то киперы, которых по логике вещей не должно быть больше одного, но к которым нужен доступ из совершенно несвязанных частей кода.

Первый пример, который приходит на ум — объект «Приложение» во всевозможных фреймворках.

> В чем проблема просто тупо создать объект указанного типа один раз в программе и больше не создавать объектов такого типа?

Создать объект — не проблема, а вот получить на него ссылку из произвольного места программы — проблема (см. Назначение выше), её синглтон как раз и решает.

> ... Чем статический член любого класса не синглтон?

По сути решение имеет право на жизнь и в каком-то абстрактном случае может быть предпочтительным, однако плюсов по сравнению с обычным синглтоном я не вижу, а из минусов:

- Отсутствует возможность расширения созданием подклассов.

  Бывает необходимость общаться не с самим сиглтоном, как таковым, а создать конкретный подкласс и общаться с ним через интерфейс базового, тогда структура получается примерно следующая:

  ```
  class Singleton {
  public:
    static Singleton instance(){
      if(!_instance) { throw runtime_error("create a concrete singleton first ")}
      return _instance;
    }
    virtual Type doSomething()=0;
  protected:
    Singleton();
    static Singleton* _instance;
  }

  class ConcreteSingleton: public Singleton {
  public:
    static ConcreteSingleton* create(T1 param1, T2 param2) {
      if(_instance) { throw runtime_error("a concrete singleton already exists")}
       _instance = new ConcreteSingleton (param1, param2);
       return _instance;
    }
    virtual Type doSomething(T1 param1, T2 param2);
  protected:
    ConcreteSingleton();
  }
  ```

  Такое часто бывает, если синглтон является абстрактной фабрикой, задней частью моста или стратегией.
- У пользователя нет возможности как-либо повлиять на создание объекта.

  В частности, передать что-либо в `create()`, как в примере выше, нет возможности не создавать синглтон вообще, если он не нужен, нет возможности ленивой инициализации итп.
- Если есть несколько взаимодействующих синглтонов, то сложно задать порядок их создания.
- Усложняет жизнь всем т.к. при первом взгляде возникает вопрос «WTF?».
- Вводит лишнюю сущность.

Comment: [Если есть несколько взаимодействующих синглтона, то сложно задать порядок их создания.] Взаимодействующие синглтоны это какой-то оксюморон. Если у Вас есть несколько объектов, каждый из которых д.б. в программе в единственном экземпляре, то логично засунуть их всех в один класс и объявить 
этот класс СИНГЛТОНОМ с полями. Заодно и порядок создания полей станет определенным.

Comment: [Отсутствует возможность расширения созданием подклассов.] Не понял что это.

Comment: [У пользователя нет возможности как-либо повлиять на создание объекта.] Тоже не понял что это.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, [Если у Вас есть несколько объектов, каждый из которых д.б. в программе в единственном экземпляре, то логично засунуть их всех в один класс и объявить этот класс] — если это принципиально разные сущности с разной ответственностью, то нет ни какого смысла их объединять... они могут быть даже из разных библиотек... например, тот же объект «Приложение» и фасад к библиотеке контроля оборудования.... по остальному дополнил в ответ.

Comment: В примере наверное класс Singleton д.б. базовым для класса ConcreteSingleton?

Comment: [нет возможности не создавать синглтон вообще, если он не нужен] Такая возможность есть всегда. Делаете пустой конструктор, а все действия, нужные для создания объекта класса, выносите в отдельный метод. И этот метод вызываете только если синглтон действительно понадобился.

Comment: [В примере наверное класс Singleton д.б. базовым для класса ConcreteSingleton?] — да, конечно, спасибо...

Comment: @pepsicoca1 [Такая возможность есть всегда. Делаете пустой конструктор, а все действия, нужные для создания объекта класса, выносите в отдельный метод.] — согласись, это уже костыльный подход... обычно в этот момент приходит мысль хранить статический указатель вместо отдельного члена... потом замечаешь, что класс `*_shell` просто дублирует все методы внутреннего, уже не нужен и включаешь этот указатель в базовый... и вот у нас снова хрестоматийный синглтон...

Answer (score 4):

Давайте для начала вспомним, что такое синглтон. Синглтон — это тип, у которого за время жизни программы может быть создан **лишь один экземпляр**. Классическая книга [Design Patterns](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) описывает синглтон как класс без публичного конструктора, и со статическим методом `get_instance()`. В более широком смысле синглтоном можно назвать любой класс с одним экземпляром, независимо от имлементации.

Теперь ответы на ваши вопросы.

1. Очень просто. Классы должны моделировать объекты реальности. Например, если вы пишете программу, описывающую планету, то эта планета в рамках программы единственная, и её удобно описывать синглтоном. Если вы пишете программу, которая управляет пушкой, то экземпляр пушки в программе — вполне себе синглтон.
2. Да, вы можете просто договориться с самим собой, и не создавать других экземпляров класса.

   Это нормально и работает до тех пор, пока в вашем проекте не появляется второй, третий, четвёртый разработчик. Они видят класс, и они не знают или просто не держат в голове, что он должен быть только в одном экземпляре. Поэтому они спокойно создают ещё экземпляр, и в результате в вашей Солнечной Системе в цикле генерируется по одному Солнцу каждую микросекунду.

   Не забывайте: людям свойственно допускать ошибки. Цена ошибки, которую находит компилятор, не давай скомпилировать неправильный код, намного ниже, чем цена ошибки, которая найдена тестерами или (намного хуже!) клиентами.

   Вы должны всегда исходить из того, что если что-то не запрещено компилятором, разработчик попытается это сделать. Этим разработчиком, кстати, можете оказаться и вы сами, если вы вернётесь доделывать этот проект после полугодичной паузы. Поэтому если компилятор можно заставить следить за выполнением какого-то правила, то так нужно и делать.
3. Статический член не является синглтоном просто потому, что это не класс, у которого можно создать только один экземпляр. То есть, по определению синглтона. В более широком смысле, статический член можно считать некой заменой синглтона, но у него есть недостаток: программист может подменить экземпляр объекта, лежащего в статическом поле. А это как раз то, чего для синглтона не должно быть возможно.

Comment: [Они видят класс, и они не знают, что он должен быть только в одном экземпляре] В описании программы сказано, что все планеты уже созданы и с ними нужно только работать. Или этого мало? Если создадут еще второе Солнце программа не будет работать, придется все равно читать описание. А если они код поправят? Плюс на минус поправят и Солнце закрутится в другую сторону. Каким синглтоном вы защититесь тогда? Ну в принципе есть люди которым закон не писан и которые в зоопарке в клетку с тиграми лезут.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: А для чего есть `private`-поля? Можно ведь было бы просто объявить всё как `public`, и просто написать в документации «не пользуйтесь этим полем». // Обновил ответ.

Comment: [ А для чего есть private-поля?] Если синглтоностроение так же важно как privat поля, то почему бы не ввести отдельный квалификатор singleton. И не извращаться с подсчетом создания экземпляров класса. Там у Александреску 30% книги потрачено на описание построения синглтонов с зубодробительным кодом.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Нет, оно не настолько важно. Поэтому отдельного ключевого слова в языке нет. Но это не значит, что не нужно подключать защиту от неправильного использования — тем более, что она настолько проста.

Comment: [Статический член не синглтон тем, кто угодно может создать экземплар того же типа, и использовать его. ] Поглядите пример кода. Там не получится использовать экземпляр того же типа. И вообще можно не объявлять о существовании типа singleton, а объявлять только тип shell_singleton и работать только с ним.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Можно и так. Но так (а) сложнее, (б) программист видит несколько объектов, а они работают как один объект. Например, в примере с солнечной системой возможность создать 500 солнц — неправильно, даже если они все внутри себя будут проксировать вызовы в один объект. В хорошо спроектированной системе вы не можете написать логически неверный код типа «завести три экземпляра Солнца, измерить их температуру и сравнить». Хороший код не должен вызывать мыслей «чё за фигня?».

Comment: В примере объект синглтона один. Много можно создать объектов shell_singleton, но все они обращаются к одному объекту singleton, что, собственно, и требуется. Опять же с помощью shell_singleton удобно регулировать доступ к singleton из разных тредов с помощью семафоров.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Да, это я понимаю: разные объекты под капотом обращаются к одному. Это необычно. И эту необычность придётся держать в голове всем разработчикам. В любом случае, технически проблем с вашим подходом нет (за исключением того, что классический синглтон куда проще), но с точки зрения читабельности программы он не очень хорош. Например: вы вряд ли сможете дать объекту наподобие `shell_singleton` правильное, хорошее _имя_. (И не думайте говорить, что имя не важно.)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Мне кажется, что ООП для того и было создано, чтобы создать дружественную, интуитивную среду для разработчиков. Вот живёте вы в Москве, ваш друг в Питере. Вы смотрите на солнце и знаете, что это одно и то же солнце. А что будет, если наделать объектов, которые под капотом ссылаются на одно солнце? Это как создать для Москвы и Питера два больших экрана, на которых показывать одно и то же солнце. Зачем эта лишняя абстракция?

Answer (score 3):

Для себя я рассматриваю небходимость использования данного паттерна так:

Если вы хотите написать какой-то функционал, который необходимо использовать в разных частях программы - к примеру, *загрузчик ресурсов*, то вы можете использовать статические функции класса.

Однако если вы хотите использовать в вашем загрузчике ресурсов функционал, определённый в каком-то другом классе, то вы, возможно, захотите использовать **наследование**. Тогда вам придётся унаследовать `ResourceLoader` от какого-либо класса с необходимым функционалом. А быть уверенным, что в программе существует **единственный экземпляр** загрузчика ресурсов, вам поможет синглтон. **(Чтобы не допустить конкуренции за ресурсы, к примеру).**

Ещё одна важная особенность синглтонов - возможность **лениво инициализировать** это все дело. Может быть, вам никогда в программе и не понадобится загрузчик ресурсов. Тогда вы к нему не обратитесь и не будет создан экземпляр загрузчика, не будут лишний раз использоваться процессорные ресурсы (вдруг этот класс у вас индексирует всю файловую систему при создании, что не быстро).

Что касается специального ключевого слова - в `C++` его нет. Просто потому что **синглтон** - уже паттерн проектирования, нечто уровнем выше, чем тот функционал, который предлагает `C++`. Однако, в некоторых других, более высокоуровневых языках (как `Kotlin` или `Scala`) вообще нет понятия *статический член*, там эквивалентный функционал реализован с помощью **объектов-компаньонов**, которые являются синглтонами. И да, их можно наследовать!

Вот как-то так. Конечно, программист сам выбирает, что и как ему использовать. Но, как сказал @VladD, зачем лишний раз держать что-то в голове, если можно заставить компилятор проверять все за вас?

Comment: Возможность ленивой инициализации не является особенностью синглетона.